# Dill failed to load back numpy arrays after loading back numpy record arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dill

all:

I'm trying to save all my data in my Python program with dill into a binary file.
My program used both regular numpy array and numpy record array. I'm having problem on loading back regular numpy arrays if I saved both numpy record arrays and regular arrays.  The problem can be demonstrated by following simple code:

```
import dill as pickle
import numpy as np

class testdill:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data =data

# numpy record array type
personType = [('name', 'a32'), ('age', '<i2'), ('salary', '<i4'), ('weight','<f8')] 


person = np.zeros(2, dtype=personType, order='F')
d = np.random.randn(5)
d1 = testdill(d)

d = np.random.randn(5)
d2 = testdill(d)

d = np.random.randn(5)
d3 = testdill(d)


f= open('testdill.dat', 'wb')
pickle.dump(person, f) 
pickle.dump(d1, f)
pickle.dump(d2, f)
pickle.dump(d3, f)

f.close()

f= open('testdill.dat', 'rb')

person2 = pickle.load(f)
d11 = pickle.load(f)
d21 = pickle.load(f)
d31 = pickle.load(f)
```

The above code will result a key error on loading back d11 object. I don't know whether there is a bug in dill package or I'm not using dill correctly. I appreciate any suggestions and comments to get around this problem. I'm using Python 3.4 on 64-bit Windows 7.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `dill` author. It looks like you've found a bug.  I'd appreciate if you open an issue on the `dill` github page.

There is a workaround, and it's to pickle the structured array last. Why does that work? Um… I don't know yet.  (note: code was simplified w/o changing test case)

```
import dill as pickle
import numpy as np

class testdill(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data =data

personType = [('name', 'a32'), ('age', '<i2')]  

person = np.zeros(2, dtype=personType, order='F')
d = np.random.randn(5)
d1 = testdill(d)

with open('testdill.dat', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(d1, f)
  pickle.dump(person, f) 

with open('testdill.dat', 'rb') as f:
  d11 = pickle.load(f)
  person2 = pickle.load(f)
```

**UPDATE:** This was a `dill` bug that has now been fixed.  Your code works with the most recent version on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of the work around. I tested on this simply test case and it does work correctly if I dump the record array at the last. But in my actual program, it causes crash of my program even without traceback messages. I need do more tests  of this work around on my actual code, as it is much more complicated.

Comment: @JohnJiang: I don't have too many hacks inside of `dill`, but one of them is for special cases of `numpy` arrays.  Currently there are a few odd cases that fail  if you pickle different collections of `array` objects, but individually they all pickle ok.  I didn't expect that, so there were no test cases for that.

Comment: I tested the work around ie. save other numpy related classes in my actual program. It still gives me all kinds of errors. Sometimes it also works magically. I think that something is wrong in indexing numpy arrays if we mix numpy record arrays and regular arrays in a same dumped file.